# Building a CUDA program with CMake: undefined reference to __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary...cpp1_ii_main

Tags: cmake, cuda

My cuda version is 10.1, and GPU is T4. My code is like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <cooperative_groups.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;




void sort_2d_by_row();
thrust::device_vector<float> thrust_2d_by_row_even_odd(
        thrust::device_vector<float>&, int, int);
__global__ void even_odd_kernel(float *ptr, int M, int N);


int main() {
    cudaError_t err = cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, 1UL << 32);
    if (err) cout << "errors occur\n";
    sort_2d_by_row();
    return 0;
}



void sort_2d_by_row() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine;
    engine.seed(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> u(0, 90.);

    int M = 19;
    int N = 8 * 768 * 768;
    /* int N = 10; */

    std::vector<float> v(M * N);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](){return u(engine);});
    thrust::host_vector<float> hv(v.begin(), v.end());
    thrust::device_vector<float> dv = hv;

    thrust::device_vector<float> res_even_odd = thrust_2d_by_row_even_odd(dv, M, N);
}



thrust::device_vector<float> thrust_2d_by_row_even_odd(
        thrust::device_vector<float>& v, int M, int N) {
    thrust::device_vector<float> res(v.begin(), v.end());

    thrust::device_vector<int> index(M);
    thrust::sequence(thrust::device, index.begin(), index.end(), 0, 1);

    int blocky = 1;
    while (blocky < M) blocky *= 2;
    blocky /= 2;
    int blockx = 1;
    while (blockx < (N / 2) && blockx < 1024) blockx *= 2;
    blockx /= 2;
    int gridx = std::min(4096, N / blockx / 2);
    dim3 block(blockx, blocky);
    dim3 grid(gridx);
    even_odd_kernel<<<grid, block, 0>>>(
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&res[0]), M, N);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return res;
}


// descending
__global__ void even_odd_kernel(float *ptr, int M, int N) {
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
    int m = threadIdx.y;
    int tstride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x * 2;

    cooperative_groups::grid_group g = cooperative_groups::this_grid();
    g.sync();

}
```

And `CMakeLists.txt` is like this:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(cuda)

if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif ()
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g3 -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-std=c++14 -arch=sm_60 -Xptxas=-v -rdc=true")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG "-G -O0")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")
set(CUDA_CUDA_FLAGS "-gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -rdc=true")

message (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})


find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)


cuda_add_executable(sort sort.cu)
target_include_directories(
    sort PUBLIC ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(
    sort ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

The error message is:

```
CMakeFiles/sort.dir/sort_generated_sort.cu.o: In function
`__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_0004cd04_00000000-5_sort.cudafe1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15):
undefined reference to
`__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_0004cd04_00000000_6_sort_cpp1_ii_main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/sort.dir/build.make:963: recipe for target 'sort' failed
```

How could I make it work please? Besides, Does `g.sync()` have big harms to the program performance, or is the impact travial?

Comment: 1. Consider using CMake 3.8 or later, when CUDA is a first-class supported language. 2. Try to avoid manually setting each and every flags (although you can't avoid all of it). 3. Some of your flags seem to conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The cooperative groups are not an issue, IMHO. That's just something requiring a recent version of CUDA. As for your linking trouble - I think it must be some sort of flag mess. I'll suggest an alternative `CMakeLists.txt`, which itself is not perfect, but is more appropriate for CMake versions of recent years. It also has a bunch of suggestions for you in comments:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.2)

# If you want to properly search for Thrust, you'll need a FindThrust.cmake 
# script, which constitutes a "CMake module". You place it under cmake/Modules
# in your source directory and make it available by uncommenting the following
# line:
#list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules")

project(sort-with-cuda
    DESCRIPTION "My project description here"
    LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

# Don't do this. Set your build type explicitly, once; and then it's
# cached and you don't have to worry about it when you run make.
#
#if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
#    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
#endif ()

# In the future, this should not be necessary, but we need it for 
# cuda_select_nvcc_arch_flags
include(FindCUDA) 

# This will set the appropriate gencode parameters for the hardware
# on your system (although you could always force it manually)
cuda_select_nvcc_arch_flags(CUDA_ARCH_FLAGS_TMP Auto)
set(CUDA_ARCH_FLAGS ${CUDA_ARCH_FLAGS_TMP} CACHE STRING "CUDA -gencode parameters")
string(REPLACE ";" " " CUDA_ARCH_FLAGS_STR "${CUDA_ARCH_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} ${CUDA_ARCH_FLAGS_STR}")

# The above may produce something like:
#
#  -gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=compute_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=compute_75
#
# But it may include older micro-architectures which have been 
# deprecated/removed, in which case you'll need to edit that 
# with ccmake and only keep what you need.


add_executable(sort-with-cuda sort.cu)

set_target_properties(
    sort-with-cuda
    PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 14
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)

# Note: I haven't added flags for compiling with warnings

# Thrust is very finickey: It provies a configuration script, but
# only for CMake >= 3.15 . And - it doesn't provide a FindThrust.cmake
# script itself with targets appropriate for CMake >= 3.
#
# See https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/main/thrust/cmake/README.md
#
# With CMake 3.15 or later you can enable the following two lines:
#
#find_package(Thrust REQUIRED CONFIG)
#thrust_create_target(Thrust)
#target_link_libraries(sort-with-cuda Thrust)
#
# With earlier CMake versions, get yourself a proper FindThrust.cmake
# script (which creates a Thrust::Thrust target I suppose) and
# then uncomment the following two lines:
#
#find_package(Thrust REQUIRED)
#target_link_libraries(sort-with-cuda Thrust::Thrust)


# The following sets -rdc=true , but you don't actually need that for your example
set_target_properties(sort-with-cuda PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

Comment: Would you please be more specific about how to config thrust ? I use cmake 3.17.1 but the error message is `cannot find ThrustConfig.cmake or thrust-config.cmake`. I also checked `https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/tree/main/cmake`, but did not find the `.cmake` files named like that.

Comment: @coincheung: Actually, that's a big headache, because recent Thrust versions demand CMake 3.18 . And there isn't a good FindThrust.cmake script which creates CMake-3-style targets. Maybe you should ask a separate question about that.